# How to convert block diagram in to circuit schematics

Tags: microcontroller

I want to design an electrical circuit for my project.

l am not good at making circuit schematic, but I am good at assembling block diagrams.

How can I convert a block diagram into a circuit design by using software? If it is not possible what are the basic knowledge I must have to draw schematic? [image] for example this is the block diagram that I want to convert so what I have to do?

Comment: use pencil and paper - having to learn to use a program while learning to draw a schematic will just compilcate the process.

Comment: Do you mean block diagram to schematic? your questions is not clear enough!

Comment: Show us your block diagram and we can give you some hints about how to implement those functions as electronics.

Comment: How many blocks and what kind of blocks are they?

Comment: You know,  a single rectangle with a writing "My Circuit" is a block diagram too. How will you convert it to a circuit?

Comment: SHow us a good block diagram if you please. Basic knowledge of web searching, common solutions and power supply avail.  You can cut N paste or draw schematic with many tools to choose from.

Answer (score 9):

Block diagram is a higher level abstraction of a design, it usually doesn't have all connections and internal structure of blocks. It is just for general illustration of design hierarchy or data flow. You can't convert block diagram into schematics, you need to DESIGN the schematics in ACCORD with block diagram and functional definitions of its blocks. The other way is possible, from schematics to block diagram, but not the opposite way.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a block-diagram for a strain-gauge-amplifier-filter-ADC

[image]

You have to chose the gain of the amplifier (here I chose 1,000x or 60dB) to provide 1 volt into the ADC.

Given my prior experiences with signal-chains, I knew a bandwidth-limiting low-pass filter would be needed immediately before the ADC.

Notice I assumed 0.01 volt out of the sensor. You have to ask yourself if a strain-gauge can ---- safely ---- produce 0.01 volt output. Thus **you** have to learn about sensor power limits.

Although the opamp gain (the lower left plots) is flat out to 100,000Hz, the RC low-pass filter has a 10Hz corner. The tool has FOI Frequency-of-interest of 10Hz, thus the tool indicates a 3dB drop in frequency response; this shows up on middle right numbers as VoutPP being only 7.07 volts.

You could describe this tool as a block-diagram design tool, with SNR/ENOB being the metric of performance as shown in the top right.

Would you have chosen to include a 10Hertz lowpass filter? if so, what R and C values to use?  is 1.6 ohm and 10,000uF a good filter? No, because that low a R value will likely put the opamp into

1) oscillation, because the 10,000uF causes enormous closed-loop phaseshift

2) output-current short-circuit-protection, if there is any high-frequency trash to filter out.

Thus as you place "blocks" into a signal-chain, you must analyze **all** the interactions between the blocks (such as the 10,000uF capacitor causing the opamp to oscillate). The values I choose, to achieve 16 millisecond time constant and thus 10Hz corner, were 16,000 ohms and 1uF.

Since the ADC will draw some input current, that current only provided through the 16Kohm resistor, a DC_error now exists. You become responsible for error analysis and error budgets, and reading the ADC datasheets.

Comment: I've seen and drawn plenty of block diagrams, the picture included here isn't a block diagram. This is what a proper block diagram looks like: http://lea.hamradio.si/~s57nan/ham_radio/tinka/tinka_bl.jpg